# Invalid blob name length. The blob name must be between 1 and 1024 characters long

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I have been working with an Azure blob storage, in which I have tons of documents (all .pdf format). When working with cognitive services (index, indexer and skillsets), running it with the storage it works fine after it appears the error in the question name. But when I check and the length is less than 1024 (I think so).
I would like to know if there's a way to find out how Cognitive services is acquiring those blobs so I know what is happening and try to change it.
Example: Tons of pdfs with any type of name (normal characters (a-z), numbers and "-") but after like 600 docs it appears the error described before.
Curiously, as I was checking which document was related with the error, the same name appeared (i.e. NAME SURNAME 1.pdf and so on for like 9 documents). Once deleted, the error appeared again with another document, completely different.

Sorry for the large description.

Answer (score 0):

As far as valid blob names go, see [Naming and Referencing Containers, Blobs, and Metadata - Blob names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#blob-names):

> A blob name must conforming to the following naming rules:
>
> - A blob name can contain any combination of characters.
> - A blob name must be at least one character long and cannot be more than 1,024 characters long, for blobs in Azure Storage.
> - The Azure Storage emulator supports blob names up to 256 characters long. For more information, see Use the Azure storage emulator for development and testing.
> - Blob names are case-sensitive.
> - Reserved URL characters must be properly escaped.
>
> *The number of path segments comprising the blob name cannot exceed 254. A path segment is the string between consecutive delimiter characters (e.g., the forward slash '/') that corresponds to the name of a virtual directory.*